# Best Way To Import Sass/CSS File Into Reactjs Component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I am using webpack with my reactjs and I do have the sass loader setup but I am wondering if I am importing the file the right way(It works but I am just wondering if it best practice to do it this way)

```
import hamburger from "../../node_modules/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.css";
import bulma from "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma";


 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Edit

When I try to import a sass file in I get an error

```
import  "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma";
import "../../node_modules/bulma-steps-component/bulma-steps";
```

they both have an extension of .sass

```
 Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/bulma-steps-component/bulma-steps'
```

Do I need another check for this?

Edit 2

I tried adding this check in

```
  test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
      },
      {
        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
      },
      {
        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
      }
    ]
```

and did this (I needed the .sass extension to make it work)

import  "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
    import "../../node_modules/bulma-steps-component/bulma-steps.sass";

But now I get

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bulma-steps-component/bulma-steps.sass (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/bulma-steps-component/bulma-steps.sass)
Module build failed:
$steps-default-color: $grey-lighter !default
$steps-completed-color: $primary !default
$steps-active-color: $primary !default
$steps-horizontal-min-width: 10em !default
$steps-vertical-min-height: 4em !default
$steps-marker-size: 2 !default
$steps-divider-size: .4em !default
$steps-gap-size: .3rem !default
$steps-hollow-border-size: .3em !default
$steps-thin-divider-size: 1px !default
$steps-thin-marker-size: .8em !default
```

It keeps going(almost seems like it is showing me all the code in the file) but the error seems to be  `Undefined variable: "$grey-lighter".`

Comment: Are you using [css modules](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules)? so that you are using class names like `<p className={hamburger.bio}>lorem</p>` where inside _hamburger.css_ you would have like `.bio{color: #333;}`

Comment: I am using the css loader. in my module area.

Comment: Should just be able to import directly then without the `hamburger from` bit

Comment: Also if `import bulma from "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma"` is a css file and it's working, seems like your webpack config is set up to resolve the `.css` extension, so you can probably omit that from hamburger.

Comment: @1252748 - Cool, I will try that though I am having trouble with the sass files and I think it is because I need to add a "test" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue when i started with react-js but then i found this boilerplate. this is having best setup of react with redux and router.

check this out: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot

if you don't want to use this then you can refer this for your problem.

Comment: I already started my project so can't just use it as my base. I am also not using redux. It probably will be good to pick stuff out out of it.

Comment: Yes check that out that might help. i've used in so many projects.

Answer (score 0):

The webpack error saying it can't resolve your CSS file means the path you have specified is not correct. I'd import the file with the extension when you are importing sass or css, just like in your initial example where the css works. That will also help anyone else touching your code to know that what you are importing is not another module, but styles.

Comment: Yea I think that is the best way as well. I did try that for the .sass but I am getting an error still.

Comment: Where is the file located that you are doing the import (`import "../../node_modules/bulma-steps-component/bulma-steps.sass"`) from relative to the root of your project?

Comment: It's located in the same project. It is the node_modules that gets generated when you use npm packages. It's root level.

Comment: I mean where is the file located that you are doing your import in. Is your file located in the root? I know that your `node_modules` folder is located in the project root.